# NYC general mayoral and comptroller election results in New York State's 14th and 15th congressional districts?

Tags: united-states, election, new-york-city

I was researching NYC's mayoral election. Two districts stand out to me that are entirely within NYC: the 14th and 15th district. I am curious about how the election went in those two districts in particular. The reason I want to know is because I saw some data that suggests that Adams underperformed Biden there, namely the fact that he got only 60% of the vote in Queens and is running behind him by a significant but smaller margin in the Bronx, the two of which entirely contain both congressional districts.

I also want to know about the comptroller results if possible because Republicans tend to do a bit better with mayor results compared to most federal elections in NYC, but not the comptroller.

Comment: Note: there is also a mail in vote that needs to be counted. It might take a while to count it so update it if possible.

Comment: #NumberFile iirc there was a meta post saying that if the situation changes you should ask another question rather than asking the answerers to update their answers. I’ll add a citation when I find the post.

Comment: Sometimes the answer writers update it -- that's why I put this.

Comment: What's the question? Are you just asking for the numeric results?

Comment: Yes. Numeric results and therefore percentages which can easily be derived from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Mayoral election, the election night results were as follows:

| CD | Adams (DEM) | Sliwa (REP) | Pepitone (Conservative) | Rojas (Socialism & Lib) | Prussman (Libertarian) | Mateo (Save Our City) | Sliwa (Independent) | Flores (Humanity United) | Stora (Out Lawbreaker) | Francis (Empowerment) | Write-In |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 40429 | 22992 | 746 | 2112 | 206 | 207 | 781 | 185 | 24 | 265 | 312 |
| 15 | 40037 | 6598 | 468 | 575 | 80 | 171 | 245 | 77 | 11 | 212 | 94 |

And for the Comptroller:

| CD | Lander (DEM) | Carreras (REP) | Rodriguez (Conservative) | Carreras (Save Our City) | Tabacco Jr. (Libertarian/Independent) | Write-In |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 41687 | 17412 | 5200 | 379 | 939 | 80 |
| 15 | 36106 | 4618 | 3133 | 223 | 360 | 35 |

To collate this data I scraped the results from the [election night results](https://web.enrboenyc.us/) from the NYC Board of Elections, as well as the mapping of Assembly Districts/Electoral Districts to Congressional District provided by Daily Kos in their spreadsheet [here](https://web.enrboenyc.us/).